# Including files from include path not working as expected

Tags: php, xampp, include-path

When I run this code in a php file:

```
get_include_path();
```

I get this result:

> .:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear

So shouldn't all files from either of these 2 directories be automatically included in all my php files? Because when I put a file with a class in 1 of them and try using it in my php file, it says

> Fatal error: Class 'FirePHP' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php on line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the `include_path`. It won't include automatically all the files in there.

The `include_path` is a list of paths from where you can include with an relative path.

So, if you write `include 'FirePHP.php';` then the file, if it exists in one of these paths, `.` (this directory), `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php` or `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear`, will be included.

Comment: Damn it, I used to know this, but I forgot... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can include a file using `include_once` or `require_once`.

eg.

```
include_once '/path/to/your/classfile'
```