# XAMPP Path to include in PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, xampp

After reading tons of articles and trying out a lot code I coudn't make it work to include a php file form my localhost. And know I cannot even specify a path in javascript code like

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/DB/ajax/ajaxDeleteRow.php?q="+commentId,true);
```

I would like to include the file: drawTableSqlString.php  which is in the same folder as my file: CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php. they are in the folder: C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax

What I tried so far:

1.
`echo get_include_path();` and i got displayed:   .;C:\xampp\php\PEAR
then I tried to copy my file into that folder --> didn't work.

1. echo dirname(drawTableSqlString.php);

I got an error:
Notice: Use of undefined constant drawTableSqlString - assumed 'drawTableSqlString' in C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php on line 36

3.
after changing path in php.ini from "include_path=".;C:\xampp\htdocs"" to  include_path=".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"

i tried:

```
include ('\DB\ajax\drawTableSqlString.php');
include ('DB\ajax\drawTableSqlString.php');
```

gives an error as aways which looks like this:

> Warning: include(\DB\ajax\drawTableSqlString.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php on line 33
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '\DB\ajax\drawTableSqlString.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\htdocs') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php on line 33

Based on other forum entries I also tried all that code below but nothing worked:

```
//************************** include DB connection INFOS
//$xajax_dir = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\DB\\ajax'; 
//include( $xajax_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'drawTableSqlString.php' );   

//include('./localhost/DB/ajax/CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php' );   
//include('localhost/DB/ajax/CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php' );   
//include('./DB/ajax/CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php' );   
//include('DB/ajax/CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php' );   
//include('C:/xampp/htdocs/localhost/DB/ajax/drawTableSqlString.php' );   
//include_path = ('.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR','C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\drawTableSqlString.php');
//include('127.0.0.1/DB/ajax/CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php' ); 
//include('C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\drawTableSqlString.php');
//FROM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003614/including-files-from-include-path-not-working-as-expected
//include_once ('/DB/ajax/drawTableSqlString');
 //include_once("C:/xampp/htdocs/DB/ajax/drawTableSqlString.php");
// include __DIR__ . 'drawTableSqlString.php';
// include '../drawTableSqlString.php';
//include('http://127.0.0.1/DB/ajax/CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php' ); 
//$xajax_dir = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\DB\\ajax'; 
//include( $xajax_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'drawTableSqlString.php' );   
//include ('drawTableSqlString.php');
//include_path=".;c:\php\includes"

//http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path
//set_include_path(".;c:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax");

//include ('drawTableSqlString.php');

//echo get_include_path();
```

Any help would be really apreciated.

EDIT:

Since I changed some parts of the  php.ini I get an error when staring XAMPP saying:

> Fatal Error: Directive 'register_globals' is no longer available in
>   PHP

Comment: You have both files on the same folders...can i check your dir structure?

Comment: what do you mean by checking dir structure?  both files are in the folder : C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax

Comment: Just comment this line in the php.ini file: register_globals = On...(like this ;register_globals = On)

Comment: I tried. I have no error after connecting to the server but the include still doesnt work.
I get the error:
Warning: include(.;C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\drawTableSqlString.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php on line 33

Warning: include(): Failed opening '.;C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\drawTableSqlString.php' for inclusion include_path='.;C:\xampp\htdocs') in C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\CommentTableAndDeleteAjax.php on line 33

Comment: But this is wrong '.;C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\drawTableSqlString.php' note the .; at the beggining

Comment: What is wrong? What do I have to write to include a file in the same folder?  the files are in the same folder. on my server it works when I include a file in the same folder like this: 'include ('drawTableSqlString.php');'           But on the localhost it doesn't work.  
Also when I run a simple ajay example which where I cannot send some data to a php file in the same folder using get. I get "Error 404"

Comment: Its a wrong path: '.;C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\ajax\drawTableSqlString.php' ...can you see how it begins?? (with an .;)

Comment: It's strange because initially the pass was set to: ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR" - also with a .;    I removed the .; in php.ini but it also doesn't work. I try to reinstall XAMPP, maybe that helps.

Comment: Give a try to WampServer too.

Comment: I reinstalled Xampp (and lost my local files doing that:(   but i am still facing the same problemes. I think I continue to work upload everything on the server. I had never include problems there. It cost's way to much time to deal with that. When I find time I try WampServer and give feedback

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. I installed WampServer and no include problems until now. I will give it a try.